# Como reemplaza las letras?

Tags: javascript, regex

Este código reemplaza la string pasado a la función de esta manera:

- La devuelve en mayusculas
- Devuelve cada letra reemplazada por la letra que le sigue en el abecedario

*Pero no entiendo como algunas partes son realizadas, `comenté` el código para explicarlo lo que **NO ENTIENDO**.*

```js
function LetterChanges(str) { 
    var results = "", vowels = "aeiou", capitalized = "", char = "", znZ = ""; 
    
    znZ = str.replace(/z|Z/gi, function(i){
       return "a"; // Reemplaza la z o Z por a
    });
    
    znZ.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(i){
      return  results += String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt() + 1);
    }); // Ahora si encuentra una letra entre a-z('i' - > insensitivo) la reemplazara por su proximo charCode(lo hace sumandole 1), pero esto no debería funcionar porque ya reemplazo la z en la anterior funcion, no?

    capitalized = results.replace(/a|e|i|i|u/gi, function(i){
      return i.toUpperCase();
    }); // Sé que aqui las quiere colocar en mayusculas pero no entiendo como lo hace, mas bien no entiendo como funciona la expresión regular.
  
    return capitalized; //Devuelve la string transformada
}

console.log(LetterChanges("codeby"));
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no se entiende de la expresión regular? Si funciona igual que la primera, coincidiendo con 1 letra y reemplazándola (que sí entendiste).

Comment: No entiendo porqué usa esas letras

Comment: Porque solamente lleva a mayúsculas las letras `a`, `e`, `i` y `u`... Así funciona (no quiere decir que sea una buena forma de hacerlo -de hecho, no lo es).

Comment: Gracias mariano, podrías poner la simple respuesta por favor, pensaba que tenía mas ciencia.. y para que la respuesta tengo algo de contenido, por qué es mala forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copio los fragmentos de tu código y voy describiendo:

```js
function LetterChanges(str) { 
    var results = "", vowels = "aeiou", capitalized = "", char = "", znZ = ""; 

    znZ = str.replace(/z|Z/gi, function(i){
       return "a"; // Reemplaza la z o Z por a
    });
```

Tal cual describiste, reemplaza las `z` o `Z` por `a`.

Esta forma de reemplazar se repite en todo el código. La función [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) permite pasar una función para el reemplazo (un callback). Esa función, recibe como parámetro la coincidencia del regex (que se asigna a la variable `i`, y espera el valor por el cual reemplazarlo como valor devuelto por la función (`"a"` en este caso).

> De todas formas, esto es lo mismo que:
>
> ```js
> znZ = str.replace( /z/gi, "a");
> ```
>
> porque al usar el modificador `/i` ya está ignorando
>   mayúsculas/minúsculas, y claramente no es necesario pasar una función
>   que siempre devuelva el mismo resultado.

---

```js
    znZ.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(i){
      return  results += String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt() + 1);
    }); // Ahora si encuentra una letra entre a-z('i' - > insensitivo) la reemplazara por su proximo charCode(lo hace sumandole 1), pero esto no debería funcionar porque ya reemplazo la z en la anterior funcion, no?
```

Es correcto, incrementa todas las letras. Y también es correcto que ya reemplazó la `z`, por lo que tanto las `z` y las `a` del texto original van a ser reemplazadas por `b`... Asumo que es un descuido de quien lo programó.

A tener en cuenta, el resultado de la función replace() es descartado. En cambio, se usa la variable `results` dentro de la función. De esa forma, se está ignorando cualquier caracter que no esté en el rango `a-z`.

---

```js
    capitalized = results.replace(/a|e|i|i|u/gi, function(i){
      return i.toUpperCase();
    }); // Sé que aqui las quiere colocar en mayusculas pero no entiendo como lo hace, mas bien no entiendo como funciona la expresión regular.
```

De nuevo, usando un callback, por lo que la función es llamada cada vez por cada coincidencia de `/a|e|i|i|u/gi` (o sea, en este caso, por cada letra). Y dentro de la función, la variable `i` (pasada como parámetro) recibe esa vocal. La función luego devuelve esa vocal en mayúsculas.

En regex, una `|` implica alternancia, o sea que actúa como un *OR*. Por lo que la expresión se puede interpretar como: `a` o `e` o `i` o `i` (sí, probablemente sea un error de tipeo del programador, por lo que esta segunda "i" es innecesaria o debería reemplazarse por "o") o `u`.

> Ahora bien, para coincidir con una letra, conviene usar una clase
>   de caracteres (que es un poco más eficiente, y más sencilla de
>   escribir y de leer). Sería lo mismo que:
>
> ```js
> capitalized = results.replace(/[aeiu]/g, function(match){
>     return match.toUpperCase();
> });
> ```
>
> Nótese también que el modificador `/i` es innecesario (no hace falta
>   reemplazar las vocales en mayúscula por su misma letra).
>
> Además, podría haberse puesto como un `IF` dentro del reemplazo anterior (con `a-z`).
>   Si ya estaba reemplazando todas las letras, sólo era necesario ver si era una vocal ahí y devolverla en mayúsculas.
>   No creo que esté bueno estar llamando a un nuevo replace() para cada condición.

---

```js
    return capitalized; //Devuelve la string transformada
}
```

Y así devuelve el texto modificado... ¿Para qué? Ni idea. No es que una función como esta vaya a ofrecer algún grado de encriptación ni mucho menos... Parece más bien un juego, alterando las letras (con algún que otro error de por medio).

Comment: Gracias Mariano por el esfuerzo, este código es de CoderByte(de las respuestas a retos que dan los usuarios) , de aquí viene: https://coderbyte.com/question/letter-changes-how-to-ignore-white-spaces

Comment: Ya veo... La verdad, te recomendaría ignorar este código y buscar alguno con un poco más de sentido ;-)